# Populate each json data in certain interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I would like to populate data that comes out of json using `$.getJSON` in certain interval.

I am able to populate data, but it all comes at once. What I need is to show each data in certain interval (maybe 3secs).

here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nyzht697/

I tried using `setTimeout ( function ()` but yet it loads everything at once.

```
$.each(transactionData, function(i, item) {

var time = '<span class="time text-light d-block">' + item.Time + '</span>';
var date = '<span class="date d-block">' + item.Date + '</span>';
var amount = '<span class="value d-block">' + item.CryptoAmount + ' ' + item.CryptoType + '</span>';
var cost = '<span class="diff text-success d-block">~' + item.Cost + '</span>';


setTimeout ( function () {
    transactionItem += '<li>' + time + date + '</li>';
  }, 4000);

});
```

this is what i tried but it populates everything at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

I save the array and the length and set a counter that stops the execution when the counter has reached the last element in the array. That is what the return does

Show one item per call until the array is empty

```js
var ajaxTime = new Date().getTime();
var dataURL = "https://adler.blockrize.io/data/";
var cnt = 0, max;
var transactionList = $('.transaction-list');
var rewardsEarnedHolder = $('#rewardsEarned');
var cryptoEarnedTable = $('#cryptoEarnedTable');
var transactionData;

$.getJSON(dataURL, function(response, status, t) {
  transactionData = response.TransactionHistory;
  max = transactionData.length;
  var rewardEarned = response.RewardsEarned;
  var cryptoEarned = response.CryptocurrenciesEarned;
  loadData()
});

function loadData() {
  if (cnt >= max) return; // we are done with the array

  item = transactionData[cnt]; // load the next item

  var time = '<span class="time text-light d-block">' + item.Time + '</span>';
  var date = '<span class="date d-block">' + item.Date + '</span>';
  var amount = '<span class="value d-block">' + item.CryptoAmount + ' ' + item.CryptoType + '</span>';
  var cost = '<span class="diff text-success d-block">~' + item.Cost + '</span>';

  transactionItem = `<li>${date}@${time}: ${amount} </li>`;
  transactionList.append(transactionItem);
  cnt++
  setTimeout(loadData, 3000)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="transaction-section bg-dark text-white pb-4">
  <h2>Transaction History</h2>
  <ul class="transaction-list mb-2"></ul>
</div>
```

Here I keep running the retrieval every 3 seconds

```js
var ajaxTime = new Date().getTime();
var dataURL = "https://adler.blockrize.io/data/";

function loadData() {
  $.getJSON(dataURL, function(response, status, t) {
    var transactionData = response.TransactionHistory;
    var rewardEarned = response.RewardsEarned;
    var cryptoEarned = response.CryptocurrenciesEarned;

    var transactionList = $('.transaction-list');
    var transactionItem = '';
    var rewardsEarnedHolder = $('#rewardsEarned');
    var rewardsEarned = '';
    var cryptoEarnedTable = $('#cryptoEarnedTable');
    var cryptosEarned = '';

    // var interval = 0;

    $.each(transactionData, function(i, item) {

      var time = '<span class="time text-light d-block">' + item.Time + '</span>';
      var date = '<span class="date d-block">' + item.Date + '</span>';
      var amount = '<span class="value d-block">' + item.CryptoAmount + ' ' + item.CryptoType + '</span>';
      var cost = '<span class="diff text-success d-block">~' + item.Cost + '</span>';

      transactionItem += '<li>' + time + date + '</li>';

    });

    transactionList.append(transactionItem);
    setTimeout(loadData, 3000)
  });
}
loadData()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="transaction-section bg-dark text-white pb-4">
  <h2>Transaction History</h2>
  <ul class="transaction-list mb-2"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, exactly. that's what i was looking. Thank you. But it would be nice if you could also write the explanation of what you did.